# Why is the div class=col span-1-of-4 box not aligning images properly?

Tags: html, css, grid

Hi all I'm a newby at coding and building my first website. I used a col span 1-of-4 for four jpg images, but they are not sizing correctly. Below I have pasted the section of I'm having issues with. Thanks in advance for your help!

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
<img src="Resources/Images/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Fransisco">
<h3>San Fransisco</h3> 
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
3700+ happy eaters
</div>           
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-star icon small"></i>
160+ top chefs
</div>      
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-social-twitter icon small"></i>
@omnifood_sf
</div>       
<div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
<img src="Resources/Images/berlin.jpg" alt="Berlin">
<h3>Berlin</h3> 
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
2300+ happy eaters
</div>           
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-star icon-small"></i>
110+ top chefs
</div>      
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
@omnifood_berlin
</div>       
<div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
<img src="Resources/Images/london.jpg" alt="London">
<h3>London</h3> 
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
1200+ happy eaters
</div>           
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-star icon-small"></i>
50+ top chefs
</div>      
<div class="city-feature">
<i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
@omnifood_london
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ? or some other similar framework ?

Answer (score 0):

use css property of class span 1-of-4

```
.span 1-of-4{width:23.8%; }
```